# Select only rows that occur at specific time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have read in `C.csv` and the `datetime` column is a `object` type.

I want to get every row that has `23:45:00` in it, regardless of date. I would like to have `datetime` as index and i would like to convert `datetime` index to datetime64[ns]. I believe pandas is designed for this sort of thing but I'm getting my indexes and data-types mixed up.

```
    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('C.csv', index_col = 'datetime', parse_dates=['datetime'])
```

The dataframe:

```
                     C      H      L      O  OI  V    WAP
datetime                                                     
2017-04-22 09:23:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
2017-04-22 09:24:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
2017-04-22 09:25:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
2017-04-22 09:26:00  39.44  39.44  39.44  39.44   1  4  39.44
2017-04-22 09:27:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   3  2  39.48
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
print(df)
              datetime      C      H      L      O  OI  V    WAP
0  2017-04-22 09:23:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
1  2017-04-22 09:24:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
2  2017-04-22 09:25:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
3  2017-04-22 09:26:00  39.44  39.44  39.44  39.44   1  4  39.44
4  2017-04-22 09:27:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   3  2  39.48
5  2017-04-23 09:25:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   3  2  39.48
```

Make `datetime` an index, and convert to datetime `dtype`:

```
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print(df.index.dtype)
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Now set matching timestamp to desired time and filter by matches:

```
match_timestamp = "09:25:00"
df.loc[df.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == match_timestamp]

                         C      H      L      O  OI  V    WAP
datetime                                                     
2017-04-22 09:25:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   0  0  39.48
2017-04-23 09:25:00  39.48  39.48  39.48  39.48   3  2  39.48
```

(The timestamp `23:45:00` was not included in your example data, but to match on this time instead, just adjust `match_timestamp`.)

Comment: How would you do this for a range of times? So to pull out all times between 19.00 and 8.00 for a range of dates. I gather that you cannot just make match_timestamp a list. Is there a simpler way of doing this rather than running it through a for loop and appending the results

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic yes, you can do this without a for loop, but it's a bit too much code to post here in a comment.  I'd be surprised if that hasn't already been answered on SO, but if not, just open up a new question and I'd be happy to walk you through it there.

Comment: For anyone else looking, I ended up using this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html