# Python: Pick an specific date from a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

The following short script uses [findatapy](https://github.com/cuemacro/findatapy) to collect data from [Dukascopy](http://Dukascopy.com) website. Note that this package uses Pandas and it doesn't require to import it separately.

```
from findatapy.market import Market, MarketDataRequest, MarketDataGenerator

market = Market(market_data_generator=MarketDataGenerator())
md_request = MarketDataRequest(start_date='08 Feb 2017', finish_date='09 Feb 2017', category='fx', fields=['bid', 'ask'], freq='tick', data_source='dukascopy', tickers=['EURUSD'])

df = market.fetch_market(md_request)

#Group everything by an hourly frequency.
df=df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).head(1)

#Deleting the milliseconds from the Dateframe
df.index =df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

#Computing Average between columns 1 and 2, and storing it in a new one.
df['Avg'] = (df['EURUSD.bid'] + df['EURUSD.ask'])/2
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image]

Until this point, everything runs properly, but I need to extract an specific hour from this dataframe. I'd like to pick, let's say, all the values (bid, ask, avg... or just one of them) at a certain hour, 10:00:00AM.

By seeing other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969877/select-only-rows-that-occur-at-specific-time-from-pandas-dataframe), I thought I could do something like this:

```
match_timestamp = "10:00:00"
df.loc[(df.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == match_timestamp)]
```

But the outcome is an error message saying:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'

I can't even perform df.index.hour, it used to work before the line where I remove the milliseconds (the dtype is datetime64[ns] until that point), after that the dtype is an 'Object'. Looks like I need to reverse this format in order to use strftime.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should take a look at [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) :

```
df = df.resample('H').first()  # resample for each hour and use first value of hour
```

then:

```
df.loc[df.index.hour == 10]  # index is still a date object, play with it
```

if you dont like that, you can just set your index to a datetime object like so:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

then your code should work as is

Comment: I liked this one because with one line I can get rid of the milliseconds and get to stay with the same dtype throughout the dataframe manipulation. I can also use  df.loc[(df.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "10:00:00")], which is better for what I'm trying to do. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AquilesPáez no problem, also you would get about a 10% speed increase using resample vs groupby on large set

Answer (score 2):

try to reset the index

```
match_timestamp = "10:00:00"
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date))
df.loc[(df.Date.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == match_timestamp)]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'strftime'. I think reset_index() function has to be filled with the datatype I want the dataframe index to have, right? Anyways, the third line of your solution works fine if I change the timegrouper line for df = df.resample('H').first() (kindly suggested by @steven-g), and delete my line in the script where the milliseconds are removed, because that command does that already.

Comment: @AquilesPáez you need to convert it to datetime first